# $location.path or $location.url doesn't trigger the ngRoute controller

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a route defines as follows:

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/projects/', {
            controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'project_ctrl',
            templateUrl: '/static/app/partials/project.html'
        }).
```

After the login finishes I need the user to land on this link, hence in my controller I am using this:

```
vm.login = function(form) {
            if (form.$valid) {
                loginService.login(vm.loginFormData.username, vm.loginFormData.password);
                loginService.setUpUser()
                $location.url("/projects");
            }
        }
```

But unfortunately the controller associated with this view is not triggered, that is ProjectCtrl is not triggered. However when I click on the navigation link which uses  in the dom, it works fine. Can someone please guide me here, may I am missing something conceptual.

**Hence the larger question is how do I redirect a user in the controller using some APIs which also complies with ngRoute based controllers.**

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the last `/` in url so it matches `$location.url("/projects");`

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/projects', {
```

Comment: Hey thanks buddy, it solved the problem. Can you please help me with the concept behind this. Isn't that '/projects/' and '/projects' both should mean the same. Django likes these trailing backslashes but angular doesn't. Is there some uniform way where both can live in peace.

Comment: It worked only for the first time, there may be some caching issue in the browser or the faulty code. I will check and update.